# Kotlin: protected variable with public setter

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to kotlin and I'm trying to create this java situation:

```
protected String aVariable;

public setAVariable(String aValue){
    aVariable = aValue;
}
```

if I try to specify the setter with a different modifier I get an error. I also tried this:

```
protected var aVariable: String? = null

fun setAVariable(value: String?){
    aVariable = value
}
```

but it tells me that the same method already exists with a different modifier (it' the default one)

I could change just the setter method name but I would like to avoid that. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: The only thing you are hiding here would be a getter to `aVariable`, what exactly is the goal?

Comment: Allowing extenders of the class to access the value while making it writable from the outside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look up [getters and setters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters) in the kotlin reference.

There you can see how setter/getter could be overridden or changed regarding visibility, e.g.:

```
// public var with private setter:
var demo : String = ""
    private set
```

Now regarding your specific case where you want to have a public setter but protected getter, you might think that the following will work:

```
private var demo : String = ""
    public set
```

But this doesn't work. Kotlin then complains `Setter visibility must be the same or less permissive than property visibility`. So: using Kotlin standard means it is not possible. Of course you can just use any other method which then is publicly accessible and just set the appropriate property from there, e.g.:

```
private var demo : String = ""
fun overwriteDemo(s : String) {
  demo = s
}
```

Comment: well.. it is... but not using the standard setter ;-)